# Page Revision date displaying on google search

Tags: date, seo

This must likely is a noob question, but I'm trying to remove the revision date that is showing up on my pages on a google search.

I'm unable to find a answer to this on google, as all answers are regarding posts not page. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to remove the dates displayed on my pages within a google search, turns out there was a hidden span tag on all of my pages that google was using to get the date

All I had to do was find the code that added that hidden span tag to all the pages and remove it.

Once removed, I waited a day for google to cache the new changes to my pages. once they were cached the dates no longer displayed on a google search.